# Pre-optimize Lua script and call it later from C++

Tags: c++, lua, ffi, luajit

I have this filter engine, that I would like to script with LuaJIT, so that I can dump all the complicate parsing/eval code that I have.

My filter would be a string like this:

```
function filter ( obj ) return obj.attribute == "toto"
```

I would have something like this in my C++ code:

```
// on first pass:
if( ! cachedLuaFilter ) {
    // this will invoke the Lua parser to declare the function,
    // possibly triggering the JIT, and return the Lua parser 
    // with the function already pre-computed, 
    // waiting to be called with arguments. 
    cachedLuaFilter = createLuaFilter( "function filter ( obj ) return obj.attribute == \"toto\"" );
}
cachedLuaFilter->eval( myCPPObject ); // obj will be the FFI representation of myCPPObject
```

I have two questions:

- can Lua pre-compile this function and let me call it with different C++ objects that have a FFI representation ?
- is LuaJIT the right solution for that?

Comment: you do realize that the JIT also has to first parse and compile the code in order to execute it?

Comment: Yes, that's why I propose to "cache" the Jited code and pass it the object after having "parsed" it.

Comment: but you don't need JITing for that. You can store a pre-compiled version of a function using the normal interpreter too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load it with `loadstring` or `luaL_loadstring`

```
local filter = loadstring("local obj = ...; return obj.attribute")
local attr = filter(someobj)
-- Or:
luaL_loadstring(L, "local obj = ...; return obj.attribute")
```

Though I should clear up some misconceptions:

- The Lua C API and LuaJIT's FFI don't mix. There are no C API functions for FFI objects; I'm not sure how you are passing one in.
- LuaJIT is a trace compiler, not a method-at-a-time compiler. `loadstring` et al. will parse the source code to bytecode (which is still an improvement), but not machine code, which is only emitted in places where LuaJIT determines that it would give a major performance boost (usually inner loops).

Comment: Thank you, you are right about the FFI objects. I found out about user data and will use that instead.